# Pandas indexing confusion

Tags: python, pandas

While looking at indexing in pandas, I had some questions which should be simple enough. If `df` is a sufficiently long DataFrame, then `df[1:2]` gives the second row, however, `df[1]` gives an error and `df[[1]]` gives the second column. Why is that?

Comment: When you do `df[x]` this looks for a column with that label, as that label didn't exist it raised a `KeyError`, the slicing notation performs row label lookup, the last one is a little surprising, it's used the iterable value as an index on the columns which is something I would not expect to have worked. Generally you should use `loc` for row label selection, `iloc` for integer row based selection and `df[x]` or pass list of column names `df[list_of_cols]` to perform column selection to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.iloc[1]` to select the second row of the dataframe (it uses zero based indexing).  To select the second column, use `df.iloc[:, 1]` (the `:` is slice notation to select all rows).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Pandas indexing documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), using slicing inside the `[]` operator for a dataframe **slices the rows** of the dataframe, this should explain the behavior you are seeing.